# SUMIFS / COUNTIFS multiple & conditional criteria

Tags: excel-formula

Column **A** has: `Apple` `Orange` `Pear` `Banana` `Mango` multiple times and in random orders.

Column **C** has: `Red` `Yellow` `Green` `Blue` `Purple` corresponding to column **A** multiple times and in random orders.

I am looking for a formula which counts or sums all instances where `Pear` immediately follow `Apple` (i.e. the row below `Apple`) **AND** `Pear` is also `Green`.

I can return `Apple` and `Pear` and even `Pear` that are `Green` separately, but I cannot figure out how to return instances of `Pear` that are `Green` which immediately follow `Apple`.

Have attempted multiple formulas using **COUNTIFS**, **SUMIFS**, __OFFSET__but cannot find a working combination.  Here is a screenshot of sample data.  [Book2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJf9C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using

```
=IF(AND(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)="Apple", B2="Green"),1,0)
```

where Col A is fruits and Col B is colors. I copied this formula from C2 to the rest of the rows. It basically writes 1  to Col C if the condition is met, otherwise 0. I then took a sum of results.

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, should return true if pear is green and the cell above is an apple.

```
=IF(EXACT(TRIM(CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2)),"Pear Green"),IF(A1="Apple",TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```